# How to use hplip for android

Tags: android, printing

I want to use "hplip" for printing from android device. Please tell me how can I build "hplip" and use in android. 
Is there are any wrapper available for android?

See hplip documentation [here](http://hplipopensource.com/node/125)

Comment: what is the "hplip"?any document please share here

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh See question I have added the documentation link.

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh Did you found anything about how to use hplip in android?

Answer (score 1):

You can static build "hpijs" that is part of "hplib" and [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/), it can run on Android.
print command like this:

```
gs -sDEVICE=ijs -sIjsServer=hpijs -dIjsUseOutputFD -sDeviceManufacturer="HEWLETT-PACKARD" -sDeviceModel="deskjet 5550" -r300x300 -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sOutputFile="/dev/usb/lp0" ruler.pdf -c quit
```

PS: long long ago "hpijs" is single, so you can get old version. here is a shell to build hpijs.(The comments of shell is Mother tongue, you can use Google Translate :) )

```
#!/bin/sh
# 说明：本脚本是交叉(ARM)编译hpijs-2.1.4

DESTDIR=${PWD}/_install
# 1.下载源码 项目地址：http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpinkjet/files/
wget http://superb-dca2.dl.sourceforge.net/project/hpinkjet/hpijs/2.1.4/hpijs-2.1.4.tar.gz &&

# 2.解压源码
tar xvzf hpijs-2.1.4.tar.gz && cd hpijs-2.1.4 &&

# 3.配置 说明:CXXFLAGS默认是"-g -O2",这里添加-static以静态编译hpijs
./configure --host=arm-linux --target=arm-linux --build=i686-linux CC=arm-linux-gcc CXX=arm-linux-g++ LD=arm-linux-ld RANLIB=arm-linux-ranlib AR=arm-linux-ar CXXFLAGS="-static -g -O2" --prefix=/ LDFLAGS=-L../jpeg-8b/.libs &&

# 4.修正语法错误 dj3320.cpp第403行和registry.cpp第249行　开头的char改为const char
sed -i '249s/\tchar\t/\tconst char\t/' registry.cpp &&
sed -i '403s/  char/  const char/' dj3320.cpp &&

# 5.编译并安装
make && make install DESTDIR=$DESTDIR

# 6.hpijs支持的打印机型号：hpijs-2.1.4/ppd查看.
#    MDL MFG名字都在ppd文件中.
```